# Node.js/ SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input

Tags: javascript, nodejs, express

He estado dándole vueltas a este problema y no le encuentro ninguna solución. Además he estado mirado en varios foros y nada. Acepto toda clase de ayuda y gracias de antemano. Adjunto codigo:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var fs = require('fs');

var urlencodedParser = bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false });
var file = fs.readFileSync('./database.json');
var db = JSON.parse(file);


router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('index');
});

router.post('/', urlencodedParser, function(req, res) {
  let reqBody = req.body;
  db[reqBody.date] = reqBody;
  var data = JSON.stringify(db);
  fs.writeFile("./database.json", data, function(err){
    console.log('File written Successfully . . .')
  });    
  res.render('index');
});

module.exports = router;
```

El compilador me da problema concretamente en la linea 8(var db = JSON.parse(file);).

Comment: Hola, algún problema de formato ha de tener el contenido de tu archivo. El error es  de sintaxis. Si el archivo no contiene un valor JSON válido, se producirá un error de sintaxis. Tal vez debas pasar como opción el tipo de codificación usado para el método [fs.readFileSync()](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v12.x/docs/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfile_path_options_callback). Por ejemplo: `let file = fs.readFileSync('./database.json', 'utf-8');`. De igual forma es bueno que hagas un debug al contenido de la variable `file` una vez que la has leído con `fs`. Saludos

Comment: Tu fichero ./database.json no es un json válido. Ábrelo en un editor que soporte json para que te diga dónde está el error. Ejemplo: visual studio code (gratis)

Comment: Gracias a todos. Pero solo me ha funcionado la primera vez que me ha escrito en el archivo, cuando intento escribir otra vez me salta el mismo error. He comprobado el formato de mi database.json y lo he depurado con vcode pero nada. También he añadido la linea que me has aconsejado, @MauricioContreras pero nada.

Comment: Por cierto algo que no he dicho es que uso body-parser en este fichero pero en el app.js el fichero principal uso cookie-parser. Existe algun conflicto entre estas dos librerias?